# Outputting the answer with a temperature converter in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was able to get the input from the user to be converted into the different temperatures, however I need the answer to be outputted as "temperature given to converted temperature". eg "100C to 373,15K"

```
let initialMetric = prompt("Which metric would you like to convert the temperature? \n C -     Celsius \n F - Fahrenheit \n K - Kelvin");
let userTemp = Number(prompt("Please enter the number you want converted:"));

switch(initialMetric){
    case "C":
        userTemp = userTemp;
        break;

    case "F":
        userTemp = userTemp;
        break;

    case "K":
        userTemp = userTemp;
        break;
}

let convertedMetric = prompt("To which metric would you like to convert the temperature? \n C -   Celsius \n F - Fahrenheit \n K - Kelvin");

let celsiusFromFahrenheit = (userTemp - 32) * 5/9;
let celsiusFromKelvin = userTemp - 273.15;
let fahrenheitFromCelsius = (userTemp * 9/5) + 32;
let fahrenheitFromKelvin = (userTemp * 9/5) + 459.67;
let kelvinFromCelsius = userTemp + 273.15;
let kelvinFromFahrenheit = (userTemp + 459.67) * 5/9;

switch(convertedMetric){
    case "F":
        if(initialMetric == "C"){   
        }else if(initialMetric == "F"){   
        }else if(initialMetric == "K"){  
        }
        break;

    case "K":
        if(initialMetric == "C"){    
        }else if(initialMetric == "K"){   
        }else if(initialMetric == "F"){    
        }
        break;

    case "C":
        if(initialMetric == "F"){   
        }else if(initialMetric == "K"){   
        }else if(initialMetric == "C"){
        }
}

console.log(`${userTemp} to ${convertedMetric}`)
```

Comment: In your case it's also reasonable to choose a canonical unit, such as Kelvin.  Convert the input unit to a canonical Kelvin representation regardless of which target unit is selected.  Then write code to convert from canonical Kelvin to F or C if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to place your conversions inside the appropriate if/else-if statements and store them in a result variable. If no conversion needs to be done, the temperature can be stored as is. The rest is easy:

```
let convertedTemp = 0

if(initialMetric === convertedMetric){
    convertedTemp = userTemp
}

else{
    switch(convertedMetric){
        case "F":
            if(initialMetric === "C"){
                convertedTemp = (userTemp * 9/5) + 32
            }else if(initialMetric === "K"){
                convertedTemp = (userTemp * 9/5) + 459.67
            }

            break

        ... // Repeat for Celsius and Kelvin
    }
}

console.log(`${userTemp}${initialMetric} to ${convertedTemp}${convertedMetric}`)
```

Note the triple-equals (strict comparison) and no semicolons (optional in JavaScript)